# SSRS Stop group in tablix being split across printing pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a tablix in SQL REPORTS (SSRS) that has many grouped items.

It fits roughly 3.5 groupped item per page when printnig, however I dont want the groups to be split up over the 2 pages, I want a pagebreak to happen whenever the group needs to be split.

I dont want to have it 1 group per page either, I know there is an option for that.

Answer (score 16):

At the bottom of the report builder, you will see two boxes, Row Groups and Column Groups. Select the Column Groups drop down, click "Advanced Mode" and then in Row groups highlight "Details". In Properties under the "Other" section, select "True" for Keep Together. and save. This should work. 
Note: I know this is old hope this helps people starting out though.

Comment: Still useful on latest RB build in 2020. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me in VS 2019. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Modifying the property **Other -> KeepTogether** of the outermost row group desired to keep within a single page worked for me using Report Builder 3.

[My KeepTogether values for each Row Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFkbL.png)

Notice in my example, KeepTogether is false for table1_Group1. I don't want to keep my entire dataset together. Instead I want to keep only individual groupings of that dataset together.

In order to see the Properties panel, enable the **Properties** checkbox under the **Show/Hide** section of the **View** tab of the Ribbon.

[My View settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBTmB.png)

Comment: The trick is all groups leading up to the outer group must all need the property set as "Keep Together = TRUE". For example, "Details > Group1" must both have the property set.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best place to start is the group-level **KeepTogether** property.

[image]

> Indicates whether to keep all sections of the data region together on
>   one page.

Answer (score 1):

I have just worked through 3 similar reports that were all suffering this issue.

It was only when I marked the group row AND the detail row to get the report to force a page break and keep the pages together.

Interestingly, I can then set the DETAIL **BACK** to false and the report still functions correctly. I have no explanation as to why, but this was repeatable.

I am using SQL Server 2016 Report Builder (the red one)

Comment: is your report contain subreport. if yes, i think we have the same issue, according to my investigation, it is about the height of subreport, when it meets to certain height, it creates blank space (so that the subreport will keep into 1 page). but no solution

Answer (score 1):

I tried all options about that. When I have a more difficult group, it sometimes happens, that the group will be split across pages. Even though setting "Keep Together" property to True.

My solution is:

- don't use multiple rows
- use one row with rectangle
- to rectangle import TextBoxes and fill them with expression "=Fields!Column.Value"