# Show column value on new page regardless of whether it has changed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, activereports

After a page-break I want the Name shown in the first column, which is hidden in all but the first row it appears in, to be shown again. Please run the following snippet to see what I mean.

```html
<html>
<h2>This Output I want to Achieve</h2>
<h3>On Current Page</h3>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Bill Gates</td>
  <td>555 5989</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>55545646</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>54513215</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>54542324324</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td>Jeff</td>
  <td>987458</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
  <td>324238</td>
</tr>
</table>

<h3>On Next Page</h3>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>Jeff</td>
  <td>987458</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
  <td>324238</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Sundar</td>
  <td>324238</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
  <td>324238</td>
</tr>
</table>

<h2>But this output I am getting </h2>
<h3>On Current Page</h3>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Bill Gates</td>
  <td>555 5989</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>55545646</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>54513215</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>54542324324</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td>Jeff</td>
  <td>987458</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
  <td>324238</td>
</tr>
</table>

<h3>On Next Page</h3>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>987458</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
  <td>324238</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Sundar</td>
  <td>324238</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
  <td>324238</td>
</tr>
</table>
<html>
```

I want to Achieve this Output using SSRS Expression. I am working on Active Report .rdlx form.

Note 1:

> I want output in .rdlx format not for Section Report .rpx Format .I
>   want to achieve in Active Report 9 version

Note 2:

> This question is about a SSRS Report (.rdlx) Active Report not HTML.
>   I used HTML as a clear way to explain my question.

Comment: Trying to understand your question, are you asking how show the name again when there is a page break?

Comment: When  Particular ProductID ,Productname come on next page and it should display ProductID on next Page .I used this Expression but its not working =iif(Previous (Fields!PShopNm.Value) = Fields!PShopNm.Value Or Fields!PShopNm.Value < 9999 ," ",Fields!PShopCd.Value  + " " +  Fields!PShopNm.Value)

Comment: OK - thats confusing, because your example has name & telephone. So to check, its your expression which is suppressing the name in subsequent rows after its first displayed? Please add all this additional information directly to your question to clarify for anyone reading it.

Comment: are you grouping the table by Name?    Can you please email our support to look into it.   This looks like it needs a page-level expression since showing or hiding is based on the page break.

Comment: Based on the OP's last comment I think they aren't grouping at all - which will be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @DaleBurrell =iif(Previous (Fields!Name.Value) = Fields!Name.Value ," ",Fields!Name.Value ) This is my Expression as i Shown you in Example but it's not displaying on next page it's Showing one time which is ok but I want to display on next page when Name of same telephone number is connecting on Next Page, I hope I cleared your doubts

Comment: Please update the question with clarifications - not add comments.

Comment: The answer is, don't use an expression to hide the repeated value of `Name` instead `group by` `Name` and then set the `KeepTogether` flag on the group.

Comment: ＠GrapeCity Team, Sir I connected to your support then won't find solution for .rdlx expression they are saying we have to do in .rpx format to achieve ths output ,it's not possible in .rdlx format  report

Comment: Unfortunately, that might be the only answer for now.  However, we'll discuss with product team to see if we can add this feature in a future release.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Sir Thanks for the solution but isn't worked for me. Please Suggest some Another solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38527069/1127428

Comment: In My Active Report Table Property  there no such option of Keep together @DaleBurrell

Comment: I think you probably shouldn't have tagged reporting services - because from what I can tell you're not using regular reporting services.

Comment: there is a Matrix control in ActiveReports 9 that allows to get the desired output. i have uploaded a sample of report on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6z0d1ozxo8wox7p/so54838759_matrix.rdlx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do. First, in the latest version of ActiveReports 13, we've added an "AutoMerge" property to the Table control that will do this for you by default. 
Otherwise, if you'd like to stick to ActiveReports 9, you can get this behavior by using the Matrix control. We've provided a sample for you [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6z0d1ozxo8wox7p/so54838759_matrix.rdlx?dl=0).